# In Flutter, how can I combine data into a string very quickly?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am gathering accelerometer data from my phone using the sensors package, adding that data to a `List<AccelerometerEvent>`, and then combining that data into a (csv) String so I can use file.writeAsString() to save this data as a csv file. The problem I am having is that it takes too long to combine the data into a string.

For example:

List length : 28645

Milliseconds to combine into csv string: 113580

Code:

```
    for (AccelerometerEvent event in history) {
      dataString = dataString + '${event.timestamp},${event.x},${event.y},${event.z}\n';
    }
```

What would be a more efficient way to do this?
Should I even combine the data into a string, or is there a better way to save this data to a file?

Thanks

Comment: check `StringBuffer`

Comment: or instead of using `File.writeAsString` try `File.openWrite` and write your data in a loop to returned `IOSink` by calling `IOSink.writeln` method for example

Comment: @pskink wow the StringBuffer worked really well, thank you!

Comment: or even without any loop: `Stream.fromIterable(history).map((event) => '${event.timestamp},${event.x},${event.y},${event.z}\n').transform(utf8.encoder).pipe(outputSink)` - thats all!

Answer (score 0):

Create a file object

write first line with column names, and after that each row (after \n) will be an event

See: FileMode.append

Will add new strings without replacing existing string in file

```
 File file = File('events.csv');
 file.writeAsStringSync('TIMESTAMP, X, Y, Z\n', mode: FileMode.append);
 for (AccelerometerEvent event in history) {
      final x = event.x;
      final y = event.y;
      final z = event.z;
      final timestamp = event.timestamp;
      String data = '$timestamp, $x, $y, $z';
      file.writeAsStringSync('$data\n', mode: FileMode.append);
 }
```